# Spring FilterRegistrationBean registering all urls instead of the ones I define?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to add a filter bean so I can authenticate requests to specific urls. In this case I'm trying to add the url prefix, `/api/v1/*`, so that all urls with this prefix get authenticated.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@Configuration
public class Application {
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean jwtFilter() {
                FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registrationBean.setFilter(new JwtFilter());
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/api/v1/*");

        return registrationBean;
    }
    ....
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

However this seems to register all urls instead of ones prefixes with `/api/v1`.

If I send a POST request, I'd get the following response:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1466406709295,
  "status": 401,
  "error": "Unauthorized",
  "message": "Full authentication is required to access this resource",
  "path": "/user/login/email"
}
```

My pom, if it helps:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something weird must've been going on, after recompiling, rebuilding, and restarting, nothing was fixed. So I exited ***intelliJ*** and re-opened it, the issue was fixed.